# Rails admin views' titles & views' links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm working with a RESTful Rails App since long time ago.

But this week I received a requirement to change the titles for a Rails App. I think it could be easy. But I'm reading the views (in hamlet)

And found the titles are not written and come from other place. I found they use things like:

`label: t("common.email")`

`f.input :password_confirmation,`

`ep.check_box :followed_issues`

`link_to t('common.profile'), csn_profile_path`

I wrote a lote of code in rails' controllers but this is the first time I'm trying to understand rails views. Is this standard? Where can I find all this information? is this the way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Rails internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

The internationalization allows use the same views but with different languages. You can find the translations in `config/local/`, there you will find one `yml` file per language.

So, when you use `t("common.email")` it will search the translation in `config/local/[language_abbreviation].yml`

For example `en.yml` should look like:

```
common:
   welcome: "Welcome to my page"
   email: "Email"
   bye: "Bye bye"
```

And, at the same time `es.yml`:

```
common:
   welcome: "Bienvenido a mi pagina"
   email: "Correo electronico"
   bye: "Adios"
```

Thus, you only need to find the translation and change it for each language and it will change the titles in the views.